# React Native Super Grid of Images fails to render images

Tags: react-native, gridview, image-gallery

I am racking my brain trying to figure out how to display images with **react-native-super-grid**. I have tried several combinations of items in the array with no luck.

here is how I am set up:

I have imported:

```
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';
```

In the contructor I have:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    // this.dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
    this.dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
    this.state = {
        images: [
            <Image source = {require('../../../assets/drawable-mdpi/NewStoryCameraIcon.png')}/>,
            // <Image source= {require('../../../assets/drawable-mdpi/NewStoryImage2.png')}/>,
            // <Image source= {require('../../../assets/drawable-mdpi/NewStoryImage2.png')}/>,
            // <Image source= {require('../../../assets/drawable-mdpi/NewStoryImage3.png')}/>,
            // <Image source= {require('../../../assets/drawable-mdpi/NewStoryImage4.png')}/>,
            // <Image source= {require('../../../assets/drawable-mdpi/NewStoryImage5.png')}/>,
            // <Image source= {require('../../../assets/drawable-mdpi/NewStoryImage6.png')}/>,
            // <Image source= {require('../../../assets/drawable-mdpi/NewStoryImage7.png')}/>,
            // <Image source= {require('../../../assets/drawable-mdpi/NewStoryImage8.png')}/>,
          ],            
    };
```

Down in my render statement I have:

```
            <FlatGrid
                itemDimension={130}
                data={this.state.images}
                style={styles.gridView}
                spacing={10}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View>
                        item;
                    </View>
                )}
            />
```

I keep getting the following error:

[image]

In the end I want to be able to read the camera gallery and populate super-grid with thumbnails and scroll left and right through them and make selections. but I stuck on just getting super-grid working on images.

I would be grateful for any help.

Garry.

UPDATE: based on Steve's guidance below I ended up with this.

```
                        This FlatGrid displays the selected pictures from the cameraroll to be included in the new story entry 
                    */}
                    <FlatGrid
                        horizontal
                        itemDimension={50} // (selected photos height) item dimension controls the number of rows visible. if you make it more than the actual height of the image it creates padding that you cannot control.
                        data={this.state.selectedStoryPhotos}
                        style={styles.selectedStoryPicturesStyle}
                        maxDimension={200}
                        spacing={1} // spacing between each item
                        renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onHandleRemoveSubmittedPicture(item, index)}>
                                <View style={{}}>
                                    <Image
                                        style={styles.selectedStoryPicturesImage} // you have to have the width and height in here to display a larger image.
                                        source={{uri: item.uri}}
                                    />
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        )}
                    />

                    {/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write **{item}** instead of **item;** in the View component and try again.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that got me going on the right track for those that are interested see above for what I ended up with.